# New dryer makes concerning noise when drum spins

Tags: dryer, laundry

I bought a scratch and dent GE Dryer (model GTX42EASJWW) from AJMadison and had it professionally installed this morning.

It makes a concerning noise when I spin the drum - either by hand or in a cycle. I am trying to get a sense of how problematic this noise is, and/or how fixable I should expect it to be, so I can set my expectations when dealing with the company.  Customer service has been quite hard to deal with for more mundane things and returning a dryer sounds like a real pain.

Here are two short videos I took of the dryer making the noise:

https://vimeo.com/344399459

https://vimeo.com/344402142

Comment: ... and here I thought my dryer sounded bad ...

Comment: i would buy an extended warranty for it.

Comment: Could have faulty bearings or could have been knocked out of whack during travel. "Professional installation" isn't complete without a test cycle, IMO, and you need to call them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GE Repairman just stopped by and took it apart:

The 'dent' part of the scratch and dent was impacting the back of the drum when it revolved. To make matters worse, the contacts on the heater in the back were arcing against the drum. So he pounded the dent out at the back so it won't make contact anymore, and is ordering a new heater, bearings, drum, and belt! It is useable in the meantime.

So in short.. not happy with the condition of the unit or service from AJM, but very happy with the service from GE.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I wonder is that when they ship appliances like dryers with big moving parts, they often have little plastic or Styrofoam blocks used to hold those parts in place during shipping and you have to remove them when you install it. Sounds almost like someone forgot to remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the belt may be partially off. While that is a standard item to replace over time, it should not be a problem when new/nearly new. If this happened on an older machine, I would take it apart (YouTube is your friend) to adjust and, if necessary, replace the belt or other parts. But on a "new" machine, call them back. That is not just to save you the hassle but also because they could, quite reasonably, claim that if you opened up the machine to work on it that you made the problem worse.

Comment: I agree that you should pop the top and front panel (the front panel supports the drum; the drum rides on pads around the panel opening). The belt is on or it wouldn't turn, but sounds like the drum is hitting the tensioner pulley or something. Could be that the belt is misrouted, pretty common if someone does not know how the tensioner pulley is supposed to work...